# Which book is best from David lay or Hoffman or Gilbert Strang for linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

Among these book which book is self introductory. if any other book is good then suggest that also.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759717/book-recommendation-for-linear-algebra?rq=1), and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870080/which-linear-algebra-textbook-would-be-best-for-beginners-strang-lay-poole), and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612431/book-for-studying-linear-algebra?rq=1), and you can search this site for more <linear algebra, reference>

Comment: Axler's book is my personal favorite introduction.

Comment: I think Lay is the most approachable for a quick first look at linear algebra

Answer (score 0):

If you want for the first course then I will suggest the book [Linear Algebra: A Geometric Approach](http://www.amazon.in/Linear-Algebra-Geometric-Approach-Kumaresan/dp/8120316282/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1472573546&sr=8-1&keywords=linear%20algebra%20kumaresan) and the book by Strang. The book by Kumaresan is a very good book. But if you want for a higher course then I'll suggest you, Hoffman. You can also see the book by [S.Lang](http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Lang%20linear%20algebra). This is also a very good book.